# How do I change a cell's contents within an if statement?

Tags: python

Here I'm trying make the cell for the days_employed column in the row that has 'retiree' in a different column into NaN. As it is, it makes the entire days_employed column into NaN, whereas I only want that specific cell in that row to be NaN

```
for row in df['income_type']: 
    if row == 'retiree':
        df['days_employed'] = float('Nan')
```

Is there something similar to `row in df['days_employed'] = float('Nan')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seems like pandas to me, you can vectorize this by applying a condition on the entire column, then assigning those cells to NaN:

```
df.loc[df['income_type'].eq('retiree'), 'days_employed'] = np.nan
```

Or, reassign the column using `np.wher`:

```
df['days_employed'] = np.where(
    df['income_type'].eq('retiree'), np.nan, df['days_employed'])
```

Comment: I don't understand what the code is saying, but it works! Hurrah!

Answer (score 0):

When you do list[column] you are specifying the entire column, that is why the entire `days_employed` is being changed to NaN. Try this and let me know if it works:

```
for row in df['income_type']: 
    if row == 'retiree':
        df['days_employed'][x] = float('Nan')
```

Note: x is the specific value in `['days_employed']` that should be changed to `float('Nan')`.

If you do not know the value of the cell you want to change, or if it changes often, then simply use a **for loop** to look for the index of the cell you want to change, and set `x` to that index.